# How to use read (get/use) internal sitecore flags icons?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sitecore, sitecore6

does anyone know how to read internal sitecore flags ?(\sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\flags.zip)
Does sitecore has some API for this operation ?
I would like to create my country selector based on this flags.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get all languages in Sitecore using **LanguageManager.GetLanguages** method. Then use **GetIcon** method on any of the laguages to get the flag of the language:

```
LanguageCollection languages = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Sitecore.Context.Database);
languages[0].GetIcon(Sitecore.Context.Database);
```

This will result in **/Flags/16x16/flag_usa.png** and you need to add **/~/icon** ath the beginning, e.g. **/~/icon/Flags/16x16/flag_usa.png**

You can get a list of all files in the **flags.zip** using the code:

```
string[] files = Sitecore.Resources.ZippedIcon.GetFiles("flags", "/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/flags.zip");
```

Also check other methods from **ZippedIcon** class (e.g. **GetStream**).

Comment: As I can see this code select just setup languages in sitecore Am I right ?

Comment: You're right, it displays only the languages enabled for the chosen database.

Comment: I've extended my answer explaining how to get flag files from the **flags.zip** archive.